# Do prescription glasses augment or mitigate the effect of the sun on the skin around the eyes directly beneath them (assuming no UV blocking coating)?

Tags: optics, everyday-life, radiation, biophysics, vision

The question is about minus correction (nearsightedness), but would also be interesting to know how it differs for plus correction (farsightedness), cylinder correction (astigmatism), axis correction.